# Kentico - Report of pages using/not using "Output Cache"

Tags: kentico

Pages --> General --> Output Cache --> Use output cache (radio button list)

Is there an out-of-the-box report showing this setting on all the pages. If not, which CMS SQL table can I query for seeing this setting?

Using Kentico 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the CMS_Tree table [NodeCacheMinutes]. But it will not show child pages that inherit output cache from parent node.

Comment: Thanks. With a couple of tests, I figured out that if the page inherits the setting, `NodeCacheMinutes` will be null, if it is set to NO, `NodeCacheMinutes` is set to 0. Here is my SQL to check if any child pages are not inheriting the setting.

`select NodeCacheMinutes, NodeID, NodeAliasPath, DocumentID, DocumentCulture from View_CMS_Tree_Joined where NodeCacheMinutes is not null and NodeAliasPath <> '/'`